# Is login history only stored for 6 months?

Tags: security, authentication, logging, login

Is login history only stored for 6 months? I appreciate it's in the [security audit controls workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/Content/audit_controls_1.htm):

> Because of the volume of data, login history is automatically removed after six months. If you want to keep it longer, such as for compliance regulations, consider using one of the Salesforce Web services APIs to copy the history records to a custom object or external data store.

But can older events be accessed through any other kind of API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the logs go back just six months. Even salesforce's Data Recovery option only goes back three months. If you're concerned that you need a longer audit trail, there are ways of doing this.

Two thoughts that come to mind are delegated authentication and regular exports of the login history.

The former works because delegated authentication moves authentication to a server you control. Regular backups of login data can be stored in a separate system, or even a custom object in salesforce.

Either option won't help you if you need it now, but implementing a solution now can spare you the trouble later.